# How can I compare rows in a database table based on a particular column in sql sqlite, like using a for loop or if statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, dataset, subquery

Guys I have this database i'm trying to write sql on to extract some data from one of its tables, TempHighF is a column on this table, so i'm trying to select all rows that has TempHighF values 10 times greater than the TempHighF value above it, I wrote it with a FOR loop and an if statement for in python using the database as a dataset on my jupyter notebook and I got exactly what I need, however writing it in SQL is a problem, please I need help. df_new here is what I want to achieve in SQL

```
very_high_temp=[]
for i in range(1, 1319):
    if df['TempHighF'].loc[i]-df['TempHighF'].loc[i-1]>=10:
        very_high_temp.append(i)
df_new = df.loc[very_high_temp]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`, provided that you have a column to order the rows - I assumed `id`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lag(TempHighF) over(order by id) as lagTempHighF
    from mytable t
) t
where TempHighF - lagTempHighF >= 10
```